# Airflow: Is there a way to copy variables from one Composer version to another Composer version using Cloud Shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-shell

I am working on a migration task, which involves copying variables from one Cloud Composer version to another Cloud Composer version using Cloud Shell.

Though, is it possible to accomplish such a task in Cloud Shell?

I have read the Airflow and Composer documentation; though, I cannot seem to find a working command that will allow me to copy variables from one Composer version to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a single Airflow CLI command to "move" Variables from one Airflow environment to another; however, you can [export Variables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#export_repeat4) from source environment to a file and then [import from the same file](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#import_repeat4) to the target environment.

Something like this:

*Export from source environment*

```bash
gcloud composer environments run SOURCE_ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
    --location SOURCE_LOCATION \
    variables export \
    my_file.json
```

*Import to target environment*

```bash
gcloud composer environments run TARGET_ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
    --location TARGET_LOCATION \
    variables import \
    my_file.json
```